# Integration of the $\int_{0}^{1}e^{\frac{\kappa}{\alpha} y^{\alpha}}y^{\beta}(1-y^2)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}\text{d}y$

Tags: computational-mathematics

Does one calculate the following integral:
$$B_{d}(\kappa, \alpha, \beta) :=\int_{0}^{1}e^{\frac{\kappa}{\alpha} y^{\alpha}}y^{\beta}(1-y^2)^{\frac{d-3}{2}}\text{d}y$$

where $d,\kappa, \beta >0$ and $\alpha \in (0,2]$

Thanks in advance:

Answer (score 0):

It can be evaluated in terms of the Wright function ${}_p \Psi_q$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 {\mathrm{e}^{(\kappa /\alpha )y^\alpha  } y^\beta  (1 - y^2 )^{(d - 3)/2} \mathrm{d}y} & = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 {\mathrm{e}^{(\kappa /\alpha )t^{\alpha /2} } t^{(\beta  - 1)/2} (1 - t)^{(d - 3)/2} \mathrm{d}t} 
\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(\kappa /\alpha )^n }}{{n!}}\int_0^1 {t^{(\alpha n + \beta  - 1)/2} (1 - t)^{(d - 3)/2} \mathrm{d}t} } 
\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{{d - 1}}{2}} \right)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(\kappa /\alpha )^n }}{{n!}}\frac{{\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{{\alpha n + \beta  + 1}}{2}} \right)}}{{\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{{\alpha n + \beta  + d}}{2}} \right)}}} 
\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{{d - 1}}{2}} \right){}_1\Psi _1 \!\left( {\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{{\beta  + 1}}{2};\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{{\beta  + d + 1}}{2};\frac{\kappa }{\alpha }} \right),
\end{align*}
provided that $\operatorname{Re}(d)>1$, $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha)>0$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\beta)>-1$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please send me the link about Wright function. I have to show reference in my project.

Comment: A possible reference is https://doi.org/10.1016/0898-1221(95)00165-U